# How to transpose the list in java

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, collections

I want to transpose my list

Assume I am having the studentList

```
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
studentList.add(new Student(101, "English", "95"));
studentList.add(new Student(101, "Maths", "82"));
studentList.add(new Student(101, "Biology", "93"));
studentList.add(new Student(101, "Physics", "77"));
studentList.add(new Student(101, "Chemistry", "65"));
studentList.add(new Student(102, "English", "86"));
studentList.add(new Student(102, "Maths", "75"));
studentList.add(new Student(102, "Biology", "68"));
studentList.add(new Student(102, "Physics", "63"));
studentList.add(new Student(102, "Chemistry", "84"));
studentList.add(new Student(103, "English", "92"));
studentList.add(new Student(103, "Maths", "88"));
studentList.add(new Student(103, "Biology", "67"));
studentList.add(new Student(103, "Physics", "81"));
studentList.add(new Student(103, "Chemistry", "93"));

public class Student {

    private Integer rollNo;

    private String subject;

    private String marks;

..........
}
```

I want to transpose this data to the StudentResultList

```
List<StudentResult> studentResultList = new ArrayList<StudentResult>();


public class StudentResult {

    private String rollno;

    private String english;

    private String maths;

    private String biology;

    private String physics;

    private String chemistry;

..........

}
```

Expected Output:

```
            101         102         103

English     95          86          92

Maths       82          75          88

Biology     93          68          67  

Physics     77          63          81  

Chemistry   65          84          93
```

What collection i have to use to transpose my list?

I tried to convert using

`HashMap<Integer,Object>`
(Integer is RollNo,Object is another hashmap)

`HashMap<String, String>`
(String is Subject and the another String is marks)

Using this i am converting the studentlist to studentResultlist.

Anybody suggest me, Is there any better way to transpose the list?

Comment: Why do you need these extra objects?  Why can't you just loop through the Students and add them in the studentresult?

Comment: @ergonaut In Studentclass English, Physics etc are values of the subject field. In StudentResult class they are fields. We cant directly iterate the student class and add to the studentresult class

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit/automated way to do that.

You have to sit down and write down the code that iterates studentList and collect the information that you need to build the other list.

Keep in mind: basically you have two objects there; one representing objects of Students class; the other one to hold objects of StudentResult class. But the computer doesn't know which attributes of the one class should be collected to build objects of the second class - unless you sit down and provide that information.

In other words: if you would be looking at a database, you would be able to run queries and other operations to build a different view on your data. But there is no database, so all the logic to build different views on existing data ... must be programmed manually.

Comment: I tried to convert using

HashMap< Integer,Object > (Integer is RollNo,Object is another hashmap)

HashMap< String, String > (String is Subject and the another String is marks)... is this the right way

Comment: I just told you: you can NOT simply CONVERT your list into some other collection: you have to BUILD the new list based on data that you can only retrieve by manually iterating the first list.